# SVM for gender classification: 100% correct results with linear kernel, but much poorer results with RBF

Tags: image-processing, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I have crafted a little program for **gender classification** based on **image of a face**. I used [Yale face databse](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~leekc/ExtYaleDatabase/ExtYaleB.html) (175 images for males and the same number for females), converted them to grayscale and equalized histograms, so after preprocessing images look like this:

[image]

I ran following code to test results (it uses SVM and **linear** kernel):

```
def run_gender_classifier():
    Xm, Ym = mkdataset('gender/male', 1)     # mkdataset just preprocesses images, 
    Xf, Yf = mkdataset('gender/female', 0)   #  flattens them and stacks into a matrix
    X = np.vstack([Xm, Xf])
    Y = np.hstack([Ym, Yf])
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,
                                                    test_size=0.1,
                                                    random_state=100)
    model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print("Results:\n%s\n" % (
        metrics.classification_report(
            Y_test, model.predict(X_test))))
```

And got **100% precision**!

```
In [22]: run_gender_classifier()
Results:
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      1.00      1.00        16
          1       1.00      1.00      1.00        19

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        35
```

I could expect different results, but 100% correct for image classification look really suspicious to me.

Furthermore, when I changed kernel to **RBF**, results became totally bad:

```
In [24]: run_gender_classifier()
Results:
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.46      1.00      0.63        16
          1       0.00      0.00      0.00        19

avg / total       0.21      0.46      0.29        35
```

Which seems even more strange for me.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is there any mistake in my approach or code?
2. If not, how can results for linear kernel be so good, and for RBF so bad?

Note, that I also got 100% correct results with logistic regression, and very poor results with deep belief networks, so it's not specific to SVM, but rather for linear and non-linear models.

---

Just for completeness, here's my code for preprocessing and making dataset:

```
import cv2
from sklearn import linear_model, svm, metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split


def preprocess(im):
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im = cv2.resize(im, (100, 100))
    return cv2.equalizeHist(im)


def mkdataset(path, label):
    images = (cv2.resize(cv2.imread(fname), (100, 100))
              for fname in list_images(path))
    images = (preprocess(im) for im in images)
    X = np.vstack([im.flatten() for im in images])
    Y = np.repeat(label, X.shape[0])
    return X, Y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of described models require tuning parameters:

- Linear SVM : C
- RBF SVM : C, gamma
- DBN : Layers count, Neurons count, Output classifier, Training rate ...

And you simply **omitted** this element. So it is quite natural, that models with smallest number of tunable parameters behaved better - as simply there is bigger probability that default parameters actually worked.

100% score always looks suspicious and you should double check it "by hand" - phisically split data into train and test (put into different directories), train on one part, save your model to a file. Then in separate code - load a model, and test it on test files with displaying image + label from the model. This way you will make sure, that there is no implmenentation error (as you really don't care whether there is any processing error, if you have a physical proof that your model recognizes those faces, right?). This is purely "psychological method", which makes it obvious that there is no error in data splitting/sharing and further evaluation.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comment, I also checked your dataset, and as as it is stated on the official website:

> The extended Yale Face Database B contains 16128 images of 28 human subjects under 9 poses and 64 illumination conditions.

So this is for sure a problem - this is **not the dataset for the gender recognition**. Your classifier simply memorizes these 28 subjects, which are easily splitted to male/female. It simply won't work on any image from other subjects. The only "valuable" part of this dataset is the set of 28 faces of distinctive individuals, which you can extract by hand, but 28 images seems at least row of magnitude too small to be useful.

Comment: Also for the train test split, make sur that the faces from the test split are from different people than those from the train split. I that you get at most one picture per person in the Yale dataset. If persons get repeated pictures, then the classifier might just have to overfit the people identities rather than generalizing by only considering gender specific attributes.

Comment: Momorization of subject faces really makes sense to me. It also explains why simple linear model worked so well. Thanks for the answer  and the comment :)

Answer (score -2):

Friend from what I understand your description of your questions and I think the explanation is simple, due to the problem with linear kernel is better than the RBF believe in your logic is correct however you should is using RBF somewhat wrong I think that it will serve to your problem, continue trying to develop a way to just use the linear kernel

Comment: Thanks, Fernando, but I was more interested in _why_ linear model worked so perfectly well, and suggestion by @ogrisel seems to be the most plausible.